# Unable to import tensorflow_text as text

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am unable to `import tensorflow_text as text`. And after installing the required packages and bundles it says

```bash
"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: 
[WinError 5] Access is denied:  
'C:\\Users\\yogis\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-jldbb52n\\libopenblas.el2c6ple4zyw3eceviv3oxxgrn2nrfm2.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."
```

Answer (score 0):

just try again with Adminstrator permission